# LORA Sx1276 send same response in every condition

Tags: networking, uart, lora

I am usign one of Dorji's pruduct. The products name is DRF1276DM. The image of the product can seen in following images

[image: front][image: back]

In the application note the producers state that the module can communicate over serial port with TTL level UART. In their  application note which can be found at http://www.dorji.com/docs/data/DRF1278DM.pdf. They state that if we send a command like AF AF 00 00 AF 80 03 02 00 00 92 0D 0A  the device will response as  AF AF 00 00 AF 00 03 02 00 00 12 0D 0A I try to check this command in order to test the device but I receive same command in my all trial. The device send me that 2400  O 8 1 DRF128X V2.7. In the application note they state that the device will send only one time this command when power is one but In my case the response is always same regardless to command code.

For checking the condition I try to use every command on http://www.dorji.com/docs/data/DRF1278DM.pdf but I recieved same respond. My first question is this. Are there any one who deal with same problem with me or could you give me any solution for this case. I am suspicious that the device get reset in every time when I try to send command over serial port. Is there any way to reset the device to default either using software or hardware.

In the application note they state that the first respond which I quoted above, will give the information for communcating device In our case I expected to communicate with device on odd parity 8 bit data size 2400 baud rate but the device only gives irrelevant or nonlogical bytes in 2400 baud rate. Only logical answer I received from device is on the 9600 baud rate. My second question is this. Is there a bug on this device setting or did I miss someting because as far as I know we cannot communicate with devices over multiple baud rate option.

PS:
I try to use their configuration tool which can be found in http://www.dorji.com/products-detail.php?ProId=61, but I got same "time out"

[image: error]

Error from device, I used 2400 boud rate and even parity but the result cannot changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, the Error Time Out error appears because of a damaged UART-to-USB converter or this happens when you are using multiple jumper wires for a single pin of the module. Try using the a single female-to-female jumper wire to connect every pin of your module with the corresponding pin of the UART-to-USB converter.

Answer (score 1):

Pin EN must be connected to logical 0

Answer (score 0):

Your UART is probably working fine, i have the same issues.
My DRF1278/76 modules dont seem to respon to me changing the baudrate in configuration parameters, it looks like its fixed to 9600 bauds, wich is a boomer

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, my issue was the EN pin needs to be pulled low. Even with the USB to UART adapter I bought with the modules, that line is allowed to site high by default. Use a jumper to pull it to ground.